# Can I manually add the fields that Sharepoint 2010 needs to PPT2007 in order to fill values to template when item is created

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, workflow, designer-workflow, office-integration

So I know how to do the basic workflow of creating a document and filling it with values via content types and SPD workflow. I am able to get this to work because of the document properties in Word 2007, but I need to automate some ppt slides. I have been unable to find document properties or anything similiar in ppt to reproduce getting the fields directly tied from SharePoint template file.

So is it possible to manually create the fields and if so how do you tie the association? I tried inserting a text box and naming the field through properties the same as the content type (what the heck....) didn't work.

is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my experience/efforts, this is not possible with PowerPoint using built in functionality.  It might be possible to code something.

Comment: i would rather do that for more control but alas I am limited to ECMA/SPD in production. thanks!